# Looking for rivers data of South Italy

Tags: data, rivers, italy

I am working on a twelfth-century description of South Italy (Calabria, Apulia and Campania) which describes rivers that are now dried up.

I am attempting to create maps which reflect the description from this twelfth-century text in ArcMap.

When I look in Google Earth I can see these dried up rivers. Is there a place to find data on all the rivers in Italy, including dried up rivers?

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: GRIN (Global River Network) is worth looking into https://www.metis.upmc.fr/en/node/375

Comment: also try [ecrins](https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/european-catchments-and-rivers-network)